# How to add a custom HttpContextAccessor to service ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I want to add custom HttpContextAccessor to service in asp.net core,

is this the correct way:

at ConfigureService method:

```cs
var env = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment>();
```

Then adding customs claims (these will be extracted by anther class).

```cs
 if(env.IsDevelopment())
 {
   var claims = new List<Claim>();
   claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "test"));
   claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Operator"));
   claims.Add(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier", "af4ab79d-f75c-44be-b8dd-test"));
   claims.Add(new Claim("CompanyName", "test"));

  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(sp => new DefaultHttpContext()
  {
    User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims)),
  });

 }
```

this way the type of both:  `IHttpContextAccessor` and `DefaultHttpContext` are mismatch, is there a way to fix this or how to do it properly ?

Comment: What is your scenario?Actually I think you need add claims to httpcontext user in middleware.

Comment: How i can do that ? well my scenario is I have an API does authorization via Azure AD, for dev environment I like to have a hard coded user since im using IHttpContextAccessor in other class to extract user claims/

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this approach? I use it to pass authentication in my integration test so I think it may work for your scenario.

```
public class TestAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public TestAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, MasterData.CurrentUserId),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "test@gmail.com"),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "test@gmail.com"),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Register the Handler in StartUp.

```
services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthenticationHandler>
```